# lualatexのエラーについて、pandocを使ったmarkdownからpdfへの変換

Tags: markdown, 日本語, latex, pandoc

pandocを使ってmarkdownをpdfに変換しようと試み-latex--engine=lualatexを記述すると詰まりました。
`! Missing number, treated as zero.` エラーが出て変換できません。
そこでlualatex単体でtexファイルからpdfに変換できるのかためそうと思い

[LuaTeX-jaの使い方 - LuaTeX-ja Wiki](https://osdn.jp/projects/luatex-ja/wiki/LuaTeX-ja%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9)

のサイト流れ通りにsample.texをlualatexでコンパイルしたら同様のエラーが生じました。

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?
! No room for a new 8.
\e@ch@ck ...lse \errmessage {No room for a new #4}
                                                  \fi \fi
l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?
! Invalid \catcode table.
<recently read> \allocationnumber

l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.141 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@string

?
! No room for a new 8.
\e@ch@ck ...lse \errmessage {No room for a new #4}
                                                  \fi \fi
l.141 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@string

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.141 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@string

?
! Invalid \catcode table.
\newcatcodetable ...atcodetable \allocationnumber

l.141 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@string

?
)
Runaway definition?
#1#2#3{\ifnum #1>#2 \expandafter \@gobble \else \expandafter \@firsto\ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \setrangecatcode.
<inserted text>
}
l.10   \input{ltluatex}
                     %
?
! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text> }

l.10   \input{ltluatex}
                     %
?
)
Runaway definition?
setcatcodetable#1#2{\begingroup #2\savecatcodetable #1\endgroup } \def \ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \@.
<inserted text>
}
l.18   \fi

?
! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text> }

l.18   \fi

?
)
Runaway definition?
#1{\directlua {require("#1")}\@gobbleoptarg } \ifdefined \@ifnextchar \ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \RequireLuaModule.
<inserted text>
}
l.77   \RequirePackage
                    {luaotfload} [2013/12/31] % v2.3
?
! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text> }

l.77   \RequirePackage
                    {luaotfload} [2013/12/31] % v2.3
?

! LaTeX Error: File `{.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.95 \ltx@LocalExpandAfter
                        \ifx\csname directlua\endcsname\relax
?
! Undefined control sequence.
l.103   \@PackageError
                    {luatexja-core}
?

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 140--126
[][]000000
)
Runaway definition?
{hoge} \par \newdimen \ltj@zw \newdimen \ltj@zh \newdimen \jQ \jQ =0.\ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \ltj@loaded.
<inserted text>
}
l.45   \RequirePackage{luatexja-core}  [2016/03/31]

?
! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text> }

l.45   \RequirePackage{luatexja-core}  [2016/03/31]

?

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.46   \RequirePackage{l
                      uatexja-compat}[2013/05/14]
?

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 46--51
[][]luatexja-compat}[2013/05/14]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
{
l.52 \directlua{
              luatexja.base.start_time_measure('RUN')}
?
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
{
l.52 \directlua{
              luatexja.base.start_time_measure('RUN')}
?
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\ltj@AtEnd ...dlinechar =13\relax \let \ltj@AtEnd
                                                  \relax
l.54 \ltj@AtEnd

 1300 words of node memory still in use:
   5 hlist, 24 glue, 3 penalty, 156 glyph, 34 glue_spec, 2 local_par, 1 dir node
s
   avail lists: 1:1,2:12,3:1,4:3,6:1,7:13,10:11
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on sample.log.
;_;  ~/Documents/16_summer/cloud_network
% vim sample.                                                            [14:26:14]
^_^/OK牧場  ~/Documents/16_summer/cloud_network
% vim sample.tex                                                         [14:26:18]
^_^/OK牧場  ~/Documents/16_summer/cloud_network
% lualatex sample.tex                                                    [14:26:33]
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./sample.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 21 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltjsarticle.cls
Document Class: ltjsarticle 2016/04/04 ltjsclasses
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.tex
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?
! No room for a new 8.
\e@ch@ck ...lse \errmessage {No room for a new #4}
                                                  \fi \fi
l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?
! Invalid \catcode table.
<recently read> \allocationnumber

l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.141 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@string

?
! No room for a new 8.
\e@ch@ck ...lse \errmessage {No room for a new #4}
                                                  \fi \fi
l.141 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@string

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.141 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@string

?
! Invalid \catcode table.
\newcatcodetable ...atcodetable \allocationnumber

l.141 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@string

?
)
Runaway definition?
#1#2#3{\ifnum #1>#2 \expandafter \@gobble \else \expandafter \@firsto\ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \setrangecatcode.
<inserted text>
}
l.10   \input{ltluatex}
                     %
?
! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text> }

l.10   \input{ltluatex}
                     %
?
)
Runaway definition?
setcatcodetable#1#2{\begingroup #2\savecatcodetable #1\endgroup } \def \ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \@.
<inserted text>
}
l.18   \fi

?
! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text> }

l.18   \fi

?
)
Runaway definition?
#1{\directlua {require("#1")}\@gobbleoptarg } \ifdefined \@ifnextchar \ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \RequireLuaModule.
<inserted text>
}
l.77   \RequirePackage
                    {luaotfload} [2013/12/31] % v2.3
?
! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text> }

l.77   \RequirePackage
                    {luaotfload} [2013/12/31] % v2.3
?

! LaTeX Error: File `{.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.95 \ltx@LocalExpandAfter
                        \ifx\csname directlua\endcsname\relax
?
! Undefined control sequence.
l.103   \@PackageError
                    {luatexja-core}
?

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 140--126
[][]000000
)
Runaway definition?
{hoge} \par \newdimen \ltj@zw \newdimen \ltj@zh \newdimen \jQ \jQ =0.\ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \ltj@loaded.
<inserted text>
}
l.45   \RequirePackage{luatexja-core}  [2016/03/31]

?
! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text> }

l.45   \RequirePackage{luatexja-core}  [2016/03/31]

?

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.46   \RequirePackage{l
                      uatexja-compat}[2013/05/14]
?

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 46--51
[][]luatexja-compat}[2013/05/14]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
{
l.52 \directlua{
              luatexja.base.start_time_measure('RUN')}
?
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
{
l.52 \directlua{
              luatexja.base.start_time_measure('RUN')}
?
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\ltj@AtEnd ...dlinechar =13\relax \let \ltj@AtEnd
                                                  \relax
l.54 \ltj@AtEnd

 1300 words of node memory still in use:
   5 hlist, 24 glue, 3 penalty, 156 glyph, 34 glue_spec, 2 local_par, 1 dir node
s
   avail lists: 1:1,2:12,3:1,4:3,6:1,7:13,10:11
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on sample.log.
```

なにか解決策のある方がいらしたら是非宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 私の方の環境(`LuaTeX version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (rev 5238), LaTeX2e version 2016/02/01`)ではエラーが発生しません。こちらの記事 [luatex - Error when compiling with lualatex file "ltluatex.tex"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290592/error-when-compiling-with-lualatex-file-ltluatex-tex) を読むと、`LaTeX2e` のバージョンが古いために発生する様です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。latex2eのversionを更新して試してみます